# Evento change de select dentro do Modal deixa de funcionar após reabri-lo

Tags: modal, javascript-eventos

Estou com um select dentro de uma janela modal que exibe ou oculta um campo input de acordo com a opção selecionada pelo usuário. Exemplo: se option=1, ele mostra o input. se option=2, ele oculta o input.

Tudo funciona perfeitamente, até que percebi algo curioso: ao reabrir o modal após a abertura anterior ter acionado e alterado o valor do select várias vezes, observei que o evento show/hide deixa de funcionar.

Obviamente, após dar um refresh na página, volta a funcionar novamente.

Testei o unbind, mas não funcionou.

```
        $('#idDivModal1 .data-pagamento').unbind('show','hide');
```

Veja código completo jquery:

```
$('#idDivModal1').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {

    $( "#idDivModal1 #campo_pagamento" ).change(function() {
        var campo_pagamento = $("#idDivModal1 #campo_pagamento").val();

        $('#idDivModal1 .data-pagamento').unbind('show','hide');

        if (campo_pagamento=='Sim') {
            $('#idDivModal1 .data-pagamento').show('fast');             
        } else {
            $('#idDivModal1 .data-pagamento').hide('fast');
        }


    });
```

Testei ainda a função abaixo (hidden.bs.modal), mas também não funcionou:

```
 $('#idDivModal2').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e)
{ 
    $("#idDivModal2 #campo_pagamento").off('change');
}) ;
```

Comment: O conteúdo da modal é carregado via ajax?

Comment: Isso mesmo....observei que o evento change não é mais acionado após a reabertura do modal.

Comment: Experimenta trocar `$( "#idDivModal1 #campo_pagamento" ).change(function()` por `$('body').on('change', "#idDivModal1 #campo_pagamento", function()`. Para monitorar o evento change, independentemente de ter sido atualizado o conteúdo do html via ajax. Tira do evento da modal e coloca no onload da página.

Comment: Benilson, só o fato de eu ter trocado por $('body').on('change', "#idDivModal1 #campo_pagamento", function() , o problema aparentemente foi resolvido... o que será que houve?

Comment: removi o evento da modal conforme sua instrução, e funciona corretamente....

Comment: sendo assim, posso manter dessa maneira?

Comment: Sim, essa forma que te passei, faz com que sejam monitoradas mudanças no body da página, caso ocorram, ele atualiza automaticamente para monitorar os elementos incluídos/modificados conforme seletor informado. Dá uma olhada na documentação em https://api.jquery.com/on/.

Comment: muito obrigado. como faço para incluir o seu comentário como resposta para essa pergunta?

Comment: Você mesmo pode responder à questão, para deixá-la como fonte de pesquisas futuras.

Comment: obrigado,Benilson!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trocar

```
$( "#idDivModal1 #campo_pagamento" ).change(function()
```

por

```
$('body').on('change', "#idDivModal1 #campo_pagamento", function()
```